# Using ViewModelToModel for classes in Orc.Wizard ViewModels and WizardPage

Tags: c#, wizard, catel

I have created a Wizard using Orc.Wizard.  My WizardPage has several backing items:

```
public LoadOptions LoadOpts {get; set;}
public string FolderPath {get; set;}
```

In my ViewModel I am using the [ViewModelToModel] to expose the classes and the properties of those classes in my WizardPage model using this method.

```
[ViewModelToModel]
public string FolderPath {get; set;}

[ViewModelToModel]
[Expose("PropertyA")]
[Expose("PropertyB")]
public LoadOptions LoadOpts {get; set; }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. NOTE: All of the example applications I can find just use simple fields like "string", none of them have class in the backing WizardPage.

Answer (score 0):

In order to expose, you will need to decorate your property with the Model attribute:

```
[ViewModelToModel(nameof(LoadOpts))]
public string FolderPath {get; set;}

[Model]
[Expose("PropertyA")]
[Expose("PropertyB")]
public LoadOptions LoadOpts {get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks.  In your response you put the [ViewModelToModel(nameof(LoadOpts))] on a different item.  If I use the [Model] will that still use the backing WizardPage and map the data to it?